# How to create Azure DevOps Library Variable Group using the data from json/csv file?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-extensions

[1]Can someone please help me on how to create variable group in Azure DevOps Library using PowerShell? The file is in .json/.csv file. This is what I have so far. I am new to PowerShell so please excuse any errors.

```
$file = get-content = C:\test\Variables.json
ForEach {
$name = $_.Variable;
$Issecret = $_.IsSecret;
$Value = $_.Value;

az pipelines variable-group create --name test -p $ProjectName --org $orgUrl --authorize --variables -$name -$issecret -value
}
```

I am trying to import all the values to Azure DevOps library.

```
Name                        Is Secret    Value
--------------------------  -----------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test1                       False        https://test1.com
Test2                       False        https://test2.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get data from the csv file through the script below:

```
$body=@{
  "variables"= @{};
  "type"= "Vsts";
  "name"= "TestVariableGroup1";
  "description"= "A test variable group"
}   

$employee_list = Import-Csv "D:\test\data.csv"
foreach ($employee in $employee_list){

$body.variables[$employee.name]=@{value=$setting.value; isSecret=$employee.isSecret}

}    

$body | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

Then you can use [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#request-body) to create variable group.

Request url:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

Request body:

```
{
    "description": "xxxx",
    "name": "xxx",
    "providerData": null,
    "type": "Vsts",
    "variables": {"test1": {
        "isSecret": true,
        "value": "fortest1"
    },
    "test2": {
        "isSecret": true,
        "value": "fortest2"
    }}, 
    "variableGroupProjectReferences": [{
        "description": "xxxx",
        "name": "xxx",
        "projectReference": {
            "id": "projectId",
            "name": ""
        }
    }]
}
```

Sample script:

```
$token = "PAT token"

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
request body
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON
```

Comment: Thank you @Hugh Link - MSFT  Can you please help with the powershell script on how to get the variables from csv file? This will help me on other scripts that I am creating.

So to create a variable group we can use this script with one variable.

Comment: az pipelines variable-group update  --name 'FileTest1' --org -p --variables 'name=Value=IsSecret'

I need to create multiple varialble groups and multiple variable group variables so that's why I need help to link the variable name to the variable name inside the csv document? 

variables (script) = name, is secret, value (csv document)

Also to create a variable-group variable, it needs a group id. How can we add this to the scrip where it resumes with adding the variable group variable

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: `link the variable name to the variable name inside the csv document` Can you give a specific explanation about this and share the your csv file in the question.

Comment: @albbla91 `--Variables` parameter in az pipelines variable-group command are in format key=value space separated pairs. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/variable-group?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_pipelines_variable_group_create-required-parameters) for more information.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT @ HughLin-MSFT, thank you for your help.